# addClass is not working

Tags: jquery

i have following code

```
$("#v-nav-exp-liv li a").click(function(){

 //code for action related #v-nav-exp-liv li a      

 //code for action related .content-nav li
 $(".content-nav li").removeClass("tab");
 $(".content-nav li.zik-liv").addClass("tab");          

  return false;
});
```

the html is as follow

```
<ul class="content-nav">
   <li class="zik-liv"><a href="index.php?p=explore">Zikrs</a></li>
   <li class="ppl-liv"><a href="index.php?p=explore&t=ppl">People</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="part v-nav" id="v-nav-exp-liv">
   <li><a href="#" type="zikr_explore" sort_by="all">All</a></li>       
   <li><a href="#" type="zikr_explore" sort_by="most_shared">Most Shared</a></li>
</ul>
```

the code related to "#v-nav-exp-liv li a" is very much working, i don't know why addclass is not working....

Comment: Please show your HTML as well

Comment: Define "not working." If you look at the `li` with a debugger, the class isn't showing in the `class` attribute?

Comment: is there an element with class `content-nav li.zik-liv` in the HTML ? Please post the HTML code as well

Comment: perftip - use .find rather than long child selectors $('.content-nav').find('li')

Comment: It's been proven by many people, many times that addClass is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code and `addClass` are working just fine : [**see example**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/eRJpw/)  - example is a direct paste of your code with a visual highlight added to show the `.tab` class activating

for every link inside the second list, it's only targeting the first link in the first list, that never changes, perhaps you're trying to do something different than that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your selector is wrong.

BTW, you could make that code more succint...

```
$(".content-nav li.zik-liv").addClass("tab").siblings().removeClass("tab")
```

Assuming the `li` selected are all siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$(".content-nav li.zik-liv")` works

Answer (score 0):

If it's *only* `addClass` that's not working, then one of two things is going on:

1. Your selector (`".content-nav li.zik-liv"`) isn't good, OR
2. You are expecting to see the change with a tool that doesn't update dynamically (try seeing it with CSS rules instead)

If it isn't just `addClass`, then you probably have some Javascript error in the code inside the `click` handler before calling `addClass` which causes `addClass` to not be called at all.